# GAPI: Sorting results based on date

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am fetching results from Google Analytics web api. I am accessing results giving different dimensions like hour, day, week, yearMonth etc dynamically based on the time gap between start-date and end-date.

Here the problem I am facing is with sort-metric parameter. For dimension = day, sort-metric = date works fine but for other dimensions like week, month and year it sorts in ascending order based on the given dimension.

Say for months, I select start-date = june, 2013 and end-date = june, 2014, the results are sorted as jan, 2014;feb, 2014;mar, 2014;apr, 2014;may, 2014;june, 2013;june, 2014;july, 2013;july, 2014....etc

But the desired sort order should be june, 2013;july, 2013...dec, 2013;jan, 2014.....jun, 2014

I need correct sort-metric parameter values for above mentioned dimensions(hour, day, week, yearMonth).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array in the sort parameter.
In this example you would have to use `array('month', 'year')`